# When will I be able to upgrade from Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04? (not as a forced upgrade to a dev repo)

Tags: upgrade, updates, 20.04, kubuntu, do-release-upgrade

After a little research - I figured that Kubuntu 20.04 has [better performance](https://computingforgeeks.com/ubuntu-20-04-vs-ubuntu-18-04-comparison-table/) (Linux Kernel 4.15 to 5.4) and is currently in a stable position. I currently have Kubuntu 18.04 LTS and want to update it - but through the Direct upgrades from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, [and not to force-upgrade to the latest dev repo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades/Kubuntu).

As far as as I know, they should have released an upgrade at July (2020) - and nope, when running

```
sudo apt-get install update; sudo apt-get install upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;
```

it doesn't suggest to install  Kubuntu 20.04 LTS in its official way.
Am I doing something wrong?
Or is it delayed?
I cannot find any more info about this.

Comment: dist-upgrade is the correct command for a Debian system, and will get you about 85% of the way with Ubuntu, too. However, the supported method on Ubuntu is the `do-release-upgrade` command.

Comment: I don't know about Kubuntu, but for Ubuntu 18.04➡️20.04 the normal `do-release-upgrade` path came just a few weeks ago. It was delayed for almost two months, because there were some bugs in the upgrade process that needed to be solved. Maybe Kubuntu is in a similar state.